# How to send File and JSON data (metadata) in single HTTP POST using NodeJS

Tags: python, node.js, http

- I want to send my file with metadata (JSON) in single POST.
- I know how to do it python.
- The question is: How to do it in NodeJS?

Thank you!

**Python Code:**

```
image_metadata = {'datalocation': 'is001', 'metadata': 'metadata'}
data = {'name': 'mydata.zip', 'data': json.dumps(image_metadata)}
files = {'file': ('mydata.zip', open('./mydata.zip', 'rb'), 'application/zip', {'Expires': '0'})}
print('Sending data')
r = requests.post(url, files=files, data=data)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are wanting to send REST requests using Node, you can use the built-in [http](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html) library..

Although, I find it easier to use [`axios`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios)..

Furthermore, since you are wanting to send file data - this isn't as simple as just sending a POST request, you have to read the file first..

Something like this should work - it sends the .zip file as a Buffer.

```
const axios = require('axios');
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');

const file = path.resolve(__dirname, './testfile.zip');
const fileData = fs.readFileSync(file);

const postOptions = {
    data: fileData,
    meta: {meta:'data'}
}

let url = "http:/some.url";
axios.post(url, postOptions)
    .then(r => console.log(r))
    .catch(e => console.log(e))
```